# How to upload files and reuse them in GH Actions?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm using this GitHub action since a year now and it worked until today. I'm creating a zip file like this : `tag_name.zip` and upload it to my server in a specific folder.

```
name: Deploy WP Plugin

on:
  release:
    types:
      - created

jobs:
  deploy-WP-plugin:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Uses Actions
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name : Composer
        uses: "shivammathur/setup-php@v2"
        with:
          php-version: "latest"
      - uses: "ramsey/composer-install@v2"
      - name: Go in Folder && Create zip
        run: mkdir ../wp_plugin && cp -r . ../wp_plugin && cd .. && cd wp_plugin && rm -rf .git .github .gitignore && cd .. && zip -r ${GITHUB_REF#refs/*/}.zip wp_plugin/
      - name: Release
        uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
        if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/')
        with:
          files: ${GITHUB_REF#refs/*/}.zip
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}
      - name: Install SSH key
        uses: shimataro/ssh-key-action@v2
        with:
          key: ${{ secrets.NEW_NA1149_SSH_KEY }}
          known_hosts: ${{ secrets.NEW_NA119_PPROD_KNOW_HOST }}
      - name:  Sync files
        run: scp -P 2121 ../${GITHUB_REF#refs/*/}.zip pluginwp-95424d@my-server-domain:htdocs/version/
```

But today in my action I have this error :

```
Run softprops/action-gh-release@v1
 Pattern '${GITHUB_REF#refs/*/}.zip' does not match any files.
⚠️ Unexpected error fetching GitHub release for tag refs/tags/wp_plugin-1.0.8: HttpError: Bad credentials
Error: Bad credentials
```

I don't know if that comes from my zip storage in Github or from the upload.

BTW : If I use the key and know host from my GH secrets, I can connect to the server using SSH so I don't think the problem come from there.

Do someone have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Try: `files: ${{ github.ref_name }}.zip`

Comment: You're welcome! You said that your previous configuration i.e. `files: ${GITHUB_REF#refs/*/}.zip` was working, right?

Answer (score 0):

`GITHUB_REF` is a [default environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables).

And, according to [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#determining-when-to-use-contexts):

> **Default environment variables**: These environment variables exist only on the runner that is executing your job.

So, you need to use the [`github` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) i.e. `github.ref_name` with the `files` configuration of `softprops/action-gh-release@v1` like this:

```yaml
      - name: Release
        uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
        if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/')
        with:
          files: ${{ github.ref_name }}.zip
```